# Select all columns with ascii code in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a code which I recently discovered :) and it does do its job and well done I might add. But, I want to check all columns instead of checking it by column. Is it possible

Check my code below:

```
SELECT column_name
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name REGEXP '[[.DLE.]-[.US.]]'
```

Now, what I want is something like this but it won't work

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE REGEXP '[[.DLE.]-[.US.]]'
```

Kindly advice and I apologize for asking many questions :)

Answer (score 2):

`REGEXP` is a *binary operator* which means you have to have a left operand and a right operand.
Like most arithmetic operators.

You could check all columns like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE CONCAT(a, b, c, d, ...) REGEXP '[[.DLE.]-[.US.]]'
```

I'm using `...` for the sake of the example, but you'd need to name all your columns explicitly. There's no option to use a wildcard for the columns inside an expression.

---

You can't set "all columns" in a single `SET` clause. You'd need to do something like the following:

```
UPDATE table_name SET
  a = REPLACE(a,char(16),''),
  b = REPLACE(b,char(16),''),
  c = REPLACE(c,char(16),''),
  d = REPLACE(d,char(16),''),
  ...similar for other columns;
```

If you think this is an unexpected omission in the SQL language, then I wonder if you can name any other programming language that lets you compare to or assign a value to "all variables" in a single expression?

Comment: Thanks. I tried it and it does worked out real fine. what about update like ``UPDATE table_name SET (all columns) = replace(columns,char(16),''). Kindly advice Sir. Thanks.